# Where Nuget Packages are stored?

Tags: .net, nuget, package-managers

I read on Microsoft Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders :

> Whenever you install, update, or restore a package, NuGet manages
> packages and package information in several folders outside of your
> project structure

So, if I install Bootstrap Package for my solution `MyFirstSolution` the package should be downloaded on my folder `global-packages` and a reference to it will be added on my solution.

If everything is right when i create `MySecondSolution` and want to add Bootstrap VS should only add a reference to my project but technically I have to download it again from the package manager not only add a reference to the existing package downloaded for `MyFirstSolution`.

At the same time whenever I download a project by third part I have to reinstall all the packages used even if I already have installed it from other project made by me.

Comment: What do you mean by *but technically I have to download it again from the package manager* ? You don't have to download anything, the package manager do it for you.

Comment: Hi, nuget cache is intended to be a local cache to avoid download entire package every time you add it to a solution/project. When you add a package to a solution/project it must be reinstalled every time using the package that you have in local cache because a package could interact directly with a solution/project

Comment: I mean that if the package is already installed in my pc I should only add a reference to it on my new project. But actually I have to go the package manager, browse the package and download it again...

Comment: There is no `download` button in the package manager. Be more precise on what you actually do.

Comment: @Oracle Sorry, now I know the difference... Be more patient with the inexperienced developers... :-)

Comment: Install and Download are not the same thing. And that is the source of your confusion. **Installing** is an user triggered operation that adds the `ProjectReference` in the `.csproj` and writes the assets in the `obj` folder. The asset files are copied from the cache. If the files are not in the cache, they are automatically **downloaded** into the cache first.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the output of the Package Manager when I installed `Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1` that was already installed in another project (ie: in cache):

```
Restoring packages for D:\Sources\github\Orace\SO\SO_72936295\SO_72936295.csproj...
Installing NuGet package Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1.
Writing assets file to disk. Path: D:\Sources\github\Orace\SO\SO_72936295\obj\project.assets.json
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1' to SO_72936295
Executing nuget actions took 247 ms
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.7045858
========== Finished ==========

Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.0864676
========== Finished ==========
```

Here is the output of the Package Manager when I installed `FluentAssertions 6.7.0` that was never installed on my machine (ie: not in cache):

```
Restoring packages for D:\Sources\github\Orace\SO\SO_72648958\SO_72648958.csproj...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fluentassertions/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fluentassertions/index.json 136ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fluentassertions/6.7.0/fluentassertions.6.7.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fluentassertions/6.7.0/fluentassertions.6.7.0.nupkg 23ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.configuration.configurationmanager/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.configuration.configurationmanager/index.json 137ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.configuration.configurationmanager/4.4.0/system.configuration.configurationmanager.4.4.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.configuration.configurationmanager/4.4.0/system.configuration.configurationmanager.4.4.0.nupkg 19ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata/index.json 150ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata/4.4.0/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.4.4.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata/4.4.0/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.4.4.0.nupkg 17ms
Installed System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.4.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash gWwQv/Ug1qWJmHCmN17nAbxJYmQBM/E94QxKLksvUiiKB1Ld3Sc/eK1lgmbSjDFxkQhVuayI/cGFZhpBSodLrg==.
Installed System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData 4.4.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash cJV7ScGW7EhatRsjehfvvYVBvtiSMKgN8bOVI0bQhnF5bU7vnHVIsH49Kva7i7GWaWYvmEzkYVk1TC+gZYBEog==.
Installed FluentAssertions 6.7.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash PWbow/R3MnYDP8UW7zh/w80rGb+1NufGoNJeuzouTo2bqpvwNTFxbDwF6XWfFZ5IuquL2225Um+qSyZ8jVsT+w==.
Installing NuGet package FluentAssertions 6.7.0.
Writing assets file to disk. Path: D:\Sources\github\Orace\SO\SO_72936295\obj\project.assets.json
Successfully installed 'FluentAssertions 6.7.0' to SO_72936295
Successfully installed 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.4.0' to SO_72936295
Successfully installed 'System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData 4.4.0' to SO_72936295
Executing nuget actions took 43 ms
Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.5080716
========== Finished ==========

Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.1262123
========== Finished ==========
```

As you can see, in the second case there is actually some downloads (like: `GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fluentassertions/index.json`).

In both cases, there is a `Writing assets file to disk.` part.
That is the actual installation of the NuGet in your project.
If you manually edit the `.csproj` to add the NuGet, this part still need to be executed.
You do it by the contextual menu of the **solution** root item in the Solution Explorer.
Click `Restore NuGet Packages`.

Comment: So the act of clicking installing for the project is only "figurative", under the hood the Package Manager will decide if installing it again from the network or only adding a reference to it if already present...

Comment: `installing it again from the network` doesn't mean much. Installing is: adding the `ProjectReference` in the `.csproj` and writing the assets in the `obj` folder. The asset files are copied from the cache. If the files are not in the cache, they are download **into the cache** first.

Comment: @Miky-Bet, the way to thanks someone on SO is to at least up-vote (and accept?) the answer.

Comment: I have no reputation so I can't least up vote your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can see at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) how the cache works, and the locations used.

It doesn't download the package again if it already exists locally, but will copy it to the local project directory.